# Convert from discrete variables to continuous variables

Tags: matlab, discrete-mathematics, continuous

I'am currently working on Matlab code, that's use discrete equations. However, to synchronize some data, I should convert a discrete variables to continuous, and discrete it with other sample times, like the picture shows [from discrete to continuous](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VvVV.png).

Do you know what kind of function that I can use to transform those discrete variables into continuous variables?
Thank you.

code:

```
clear all; close all; clc; 
Bl=1/3; 
Br=1/3; 
Bt=1/3; 
a= 90/3600; %hours
b = 45; 
Ts = 1/3600; 
LEAVEa = [6000.*ones(1,b) 6000.*ones(1,(a*3600)-b)]; 
LEAVEa = repmat(LEAVEa',20,1);
LEAVEb = [6000.*ones(1,b) zeros(1,(a*3600)-b)]; 
LEAVEb = repmat(LEAVEb',20,1);

for Ka = 1:1:1800

    % Enter flow
  ENTERba(Ka) = (LEAVEa(Ka)*Bl)+ (LEAVEb(Ka)*Bt); %The flow rate entering link (b,a)
  ENT(Ka) = ENTERba(Ka)*Ts;  % sample time: 1s

end

%convert the discrete variable 'ENT' to continuous variable 

ENTc = d2c(ENT);

%convert the  continuous variable 'ENT' todiscrete variable with other
%sample time 15s
ENT1 = d2c(ENTc,15/3600);
```

Comment: Could you provide some example code of what you tried to use to implement your question?

Comment: I can provide it, but it doesn't have the synchronization part that's I ask for. The main goal is to use a common control time interval need to control the network model which has different intersections, so that intersections can communicate with each other and be synchronous. That's why I need to convert the discret variable to continuous one, and discretise it with other sample time

Comment: Generally, the kind of help that is best is help that explains why something wont work in code. We can't specifically help you if you don't provide specific details and specific code about your problem. We will only be able to help you generically.

Comment: If I understand correctly the goal is actually to achieve different sample times and not to move to continuous signals. If so you might want to look into resampling of data instead on focusing on making the transition from discrete to continous

Comment: Thank you @medicine_man, I add the code

Comment: Thank you @MichaelC. Can you explain to me how can I fixe it?

Comment: Well, if you really want to go from 1 second to 15 seconds sampling period you can simply decimate your signal by "throwing away" 14 samples, e.g. ENT1 = ENT(1:14:numel(ENT)). Please note that your new sampling period of 15 seconds still need to comply with the Nyquist theorem so you do not loose information in the process of downsampling

Comment: Thank you @MichaelC. It's a good idea. I should pay attention with Nyquist theorem as you said. But if we don't have a relation between the 2 sample times, like 4s and 5s, how can I resample it? Thank you

Comment: You can resample your signal by manipulating the frequency response of your signal. If you want to go from a lower to a higher sampling period you have to strip some of your frequency bins of your frequency response. Here is some code that allows you to resample your signal [code](https://www.dsprelated.com/showcode/54.php)